# Linking and compiling error with rviz

Tags: c++, c++11, ros, ogre

I am trying to load a urdf file using OGRE but I am having some issue while compiling. Below is my make file

```
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -w -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/OGRE
LIBS = -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lOgreMain  -lboost_system

EXEC = run
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)

#Main target
all: $(OBJECTS)
     $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS)

#To obtain object files
%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

I get the following error:

```
main.o: In function `addLink(boost::shared_ptr<urdf::Link const>)':
main.cc:(.text+0x535): undefined reference to `rviz::loadMeshFromResource(std::string const&)'
main.o: In function `initModel(char const*)':
main.cc:(.text+0x134e): undefined reference to `urdf::Model::initFile(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any idea on how to fix it.

Comment: _"I am guessing it is some linking problem."_ Sure it is. Did you try to call `urdf::Model::initFile(std::string const&)` with `myString.c_str()`??

Comment: The function  signature is correct: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/urdf/html/classurdf_1_1Model.html

Comment: Looks like you're missing to link that `urdf` library (stub).

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. I added -lurdf and -lrviz

```
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -w -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/OGRE -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -I/opt/ros/indigo/include/kdl
LIBS = -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lOgreMain -lboost_system -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib -lurdf -lrviz

EXEC = run
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)

#Main target  
all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS)

#To obtain object files
%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```